# How to import and export module using systemjs in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, systemjs

Does anyone know how to export module using systemjs in TypeScript? I got the error: `TS1148 cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided`.

Here is my code;
animal.ts

```
export class Animal {
    color: string;
    age: number;

    constructor(color: string, age:number) {
        this.color = color;
        this.age = age;
    }

    add(animal: Animal) {
        return new Animal(this.color + animal.color, this.age + animal.age);
    }
}
```

dog.ts

```
import {Animal} from './animal';

var animal1 = new Animal("red", 1);
var animal2 = new Animal("yellow", 2);
var animal3 = animal1.add(animal2);
console.log('Combine Two Animals' + animal3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify your typescript compiler options in your system config. There are many options that can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler%20Options)

```
System.config({
    typescriptOptions:{
        module: 'system'
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I added the following code to tsconfig.json               "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "system"}                                                                                          Then it works.

Comment: But then another error came: system is not defined. Do you know how to solve it? Do I need to include both animal.js and dog.js file to my html file? I am new to TypeScript. Do you know any good resources that can help me with TypeScript and systemjs? It seems most website uses nodejs to import module, I am wonder the benefit to use systemjs to import module? Thanks.

Comment: The browser cannot import modules, this is why SystemJS, webpack, browserify, requirejs, etc. exist. I would recommend reading the documentation on the SystemJS repo. You have probably forgotten a `<script>` tag for system in your html and no you do not add `<script>` tags for your compiled .js files. System will inject them for you.